# renaming project names is not working

Tags: gradle

In my settings.gradle file, I originally had this which works

```
include 'server', 'webapp'
```

I modify it to this and it breaks

```
include 'server', 'webapp'

modifyProjectNames(rootProject, "sdi-")

def modifyProjectNames(project, prefix) {
  project.children.each {
        it.name = prefix + it.name
  }
}
```

It says "project with path ':webapp' could not be found in root project 'SDI'" so I modify my file to this instead

```
include 'master', 'sdi-webapp'

modifyProjectNames(rootProject, "sdi-")

def modifyProjectNames(project, prefix) {
  project.children.each {
        it.name = prefix + it.name
  }
}
```

I get the same exact failure yet I have no :webapp in settings.gradle so it must be my main gradle build file so I rename that project now as well to :sdi-webapp so now the error changes slightly to

```
Project with path ':sdi-webapp' could not be found in root project 'SDI'.
```

I have a project structure like so

SDI
 - server
 - webapp

and I want all the project names to be sdi-server and sdi-webapp, etc. etc. BUT I want the directories to be called

```
/SDI/server instead of /SDI/sdiserver
/SDI/webapp instead of /SDI/sdiwebapp
```

ie. no sense in being redundant there.

**EDIT**

I tried the first answer on another project like so

```
include 'master', 'toneserver','webserver'

modifyProjectNames(rootProject, "sdi-")

def modifyProjectNames(project, prefix) {
  project.children.each {
        it.name = prefix + it.name
  }
}

rootProject.children.each {proj ->
  proj.projectDir = file(proj.name - "sdi-")
}
```

It simply failed with

```
Project with path ':toneserver' could not be found in root project 'stserver'
```

It kind of works if you go through your build.gradle file and modify EVERY reference to also have the prefix which kind of defeats that programming rule of trying not to repeat yourself :( :( so if I ever want to modify the prefix, I have to do an ugly find and replace :(...ick.  but it does work.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a workaround, you ca try to use the projectnames you prefere (SDI-...) in your include calls and change the projectDir of each subproject:

```
rootproject.children.each{proj->
    proj.projectDir = file(proj.name - "SDI-")
}
```

cheers,
rene

Comment: didn't work. I edited the question with my try of adding that code, but it still can't find the project.

Comment: ok, I found out it works just not like I would prefer as I have to modify the build.gradle file and all it's references :(.